# Python Max Function in Field Calculator for Date values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, date, arcgis-10.5

I have 4 fields with Date Time values, and created a new field (Date type as well) which takes the most recent date from these 4 fields. I have tried using the Max python in the field calculator to populate this new field, but it does not use the most recent date from these 4 fields. Does this function not work with Datetime values, or is there another function for this that I am not able to find on these forums.

```
max([!field1!, !field2!, !field3!, !field4!])
```

I am on 10.5.  When I have two fields that have a date within the same month, it will not read the rest of the date correctly. (See picture attached)

[image]

When I run the following updated code it fails and says it is a syntax error.

[image]

[image]

With the current code, it reads the first number in the day to select the most recent date. (As shown below). It does not use the correct chronological format, even though the strptime format worked previously.
[image]

Comment: It works for me ( `max( [!Date1!, !Date2!]` ), but `max( !Date1!, !Date2! )` also works. I am on ArcGIS 10.5. Which version do you use? Also, what kind of values do you have in your fields, please post. Also, make sure all of them are of `Date` type.

Comment: I am also on 10.5, but when I have two fields that have a date within the same month, it will not read the rest of the date correctly. (See picture attached)

Comment: Which field is the result of calculation? Which field do you expect to be used for `max`?

Comment: Can you please show the code you have used (as text) and also the column names for your screenshot that you added today?  The code in my answer doesn't look at days or months etc., but at a datetime object, so it should just be returning the max value.  If it's not then there may be an issue with the data or you've missed the field in the code?  It's hard to tell without a bit more.

Answer (score 8):

You need to convert your date into datetime object for `max()` to work correctly.  It appears field calculator doesn't see the value as a datetime object.  You may need to adjust the date format to suit your region date settings.  See [Strptime Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) in the Python docs.

Using the Python Parser, select Show Codeblock.  In the Pre-logic script code:

```
from datetime import datetime
def dtmax(*args):
    f = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
    dlist= list()
    for d in args:
        if d:
            dlist.append(datetime.strptime(d, f))
    return max(dlist)
```

Expression:

```
dtmax(!DateField1!, !DateField2!, !DateField3!, !DateField4!)
```

Comment: Would be nice if this was generalized as `dtmax(*args)` instead of requiring 4 fields exactly.

Comment: @Paul Good idea, updated.

Comment: With args I do not need to list the fields?

Comment: @Purplepeopleeater You will need to list the fields that you want in the expression (the second box in the Field Calculator), but it's not restricted to 4 fields - you could select 2 fields or 16 fields if you wanted.  My first suggested answer *required* you to use 4 fields.

Comment: I have the expression with the Field names but am unable to get this code to work, it fails when I try to run it. I have the following error; ERROR 000989
Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)

Comment: @Purplepeopleeater What does it do?  Can you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/244288/edit) your question to update

Comment: I have updated my question to show the issue. @Midavalo

Comment: Have you checked "show codeblock"? Can you update your actual question rather than your comment? That way you can post your code and errors and maybe a screenshot to help figure out why my code isn't working

Comment: @Purplepeopleeater you're missing the `f` at the start of `from`

Comment: I added the f , but will now only populate the field if there are values in all four fields, and remain NULL if there are any NULL values.

Comment: @Purplepeopleeater I have updated my answer to deal with `NULL`

Comment: @Purplepeopleeater I'm trying to re-add the image showing my field calculator but it's giving me an error.  I'll try again later, but the code above should work

Comment: Yes most definitely! The code did populate the field, even if there was a NULL value, but it is now not populating it with the most recent date. @Midavalo

Comment: You shouldn't need a temporary list `max(datetime.strptime(d, f) for d in args if d is not None)`

Comment: @Paul That's correct, and how I had first written it while testing, however when learning I prefer things written out as (in my opinion) it can make things a bit clearer as to what is happening in the code.  Once Python is more understood by the user, then we can look at other ways to write it.

Comment: In this script it is not reading the month and year in the correct order anymore, as it did in the first edit you had of the script, is it related to the Strptime behavior?

Comment: @Purplepeopleeater You need to ensure that `f = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'` is set to the correct date format to match your data and region settings.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: @Midavalo that is the correct format, and it worked the first time, but now seems to only read the first number of the day to select the most recent date.

Comment: @Purplepeopleeater Please give more info.  Edit your question and add a description and some detail about what is happening now.  Don't remove anything from your existing question, just add to the bottom of it.